# Sync 2 database schema using goldengate

Tags: oracle

I have 2 same oracle database schemas, for example: **HR** (exists in **Site1**) and **HR_COPY** (exists in **Site2**).  There are no internet connections between **Site1** and **Site2**.  Is there any way to Sync those schema together by importing the dump of **HR_COPY** (from **Site2**) to the **HR** database on **Site1** using oracle goldengate (or may be any other tools)?...

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to look at the site tour (help --> site tour), you get a badge for it!

Answer (score 1):

I did not try this way but it should work

1. Install GoldenGate on both sites.
2. Create extract for that table.
3. Move trail files to target system whenever you want.
4. Create replicat for those trail files.

It is better if you can automate 3rd step.